# Hide product page based on user role and taxonomy term

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I'm trying to redirect customers back to the shop page based on the customer's role and the product's taxonomy term.

The difference here is I want to redirect if the product DOES NOT have the chosen term. This is because products have multiple terms. What I have at the moment does the opposite of what I need, it redirects the correct products only.

These are the rules I'm trying to achieve:

- Page **IS** a single product page
- User **IS** 'logged_in'
- User role **IS** 'super_wholesale_customer'
- Product **DOES NOT** contain the term '380'

This is what I have so far:

```
// On single product pages, redirect to shop and display a custom notice for specific products
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wcpp_redirect_hiding_product_detail' );
function wcpp_redirect_hiding_product_detail() {

if ( is_product() ) {

    if ( ( is_user_logged_in() || ! current_user_can('super_wholesale_customer') )
    && has_term( '380', 'Role' ) ) {
        wc_add_notice(__("Sorry, but you are not allowed yet to see this product."), 'notice' );
        $redirect_url = get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_shop_page_id') );
        wp_redirect($redirect_url);
        exit(); // Always exit
    };
    
} 
}
```

Comment: You could set a variable for anything other than a value you want to avoid by using less than and more than operators. I'm looking for anything other than apple: if ($variable <> "apple") { //do stuff }

Comment: Hi @SJacks, that wouldn't work because each product can have multiple taxonomy terms.

Comment: Right. The rules you posted above need to be calculated and set to a variable that equals either a value or a state like true or false. I do this quite often, for example by first checking a cookie is set and then seeing what that cookie value corresponds to in a table then creating a condition for it.